# mod-rewrite sometimes exposing underlying URL - Odd Behaviour

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm battling with mod_rewrite. I have the following 2 rules Both direct to example.com/products.php

(NB the 1st line of each rule is just to enforce a trailing forwardslash )

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#RULE 1
RewriteRule ^products$ /products/ [R]
RewriteRule ^products/$ products.php [L]

#RULE 2
RewriteRule ^products/hardware$ /products/hardware/ [R]
RewriteRule ^products/hardware/$ products.php [L]**
```

Rule 1 intended to map `/products/` to `products.php`

Rule 2 intended to map `/products/hardware/` to `products.php`

My issue is rule 1 seems to work fine and the URL shown in the browser is `example.com/products/`
But when I enter `example.com/products/hardware/` into the browser it displays the correct page BUT the URL changes back to `example.com/products.php` (exposing the underlying url)

Any idea why rule 2 is causing the underlying URL to be displayed?

cheers

Mark

Comment: Always combine a redirect with a L flag. So `[R]` should become `[R,L]`. Let me know if you're still having trouble after changing this.

Comment: Hi, the [r] flags were a bit of a late addition while I was testing. I can't add the [L] flag to the first part of the rule as it would stop processing and it's actually the second part of the rul that does the actual redirect. Take rule 1, the 1st part just changes `/products` to `/products/` and it's the 2nd part that does the actual redirect of `/products/` to `products.php`

Comment: No need to get abrupt.I'm happy to listen to advice. My understanding of the L flag is to stop processing at that rule??. In that case surely when the user tries to go to `mysite/products` the first part of the rule will change the url to `mysite/products/` and an [L] flag will stop processing preventing the second part of the rule from running (the bit that does the actual redirection to products.php)??
I asked my question on here because I'm trying to understand this behaviour and reconcile it with what I already understand (which may be wrong).

Comment: Anyway I've just reuploaded my (unchanged) .htaccess file again to retest and now it's behaving properly so I think there may be a strange issue with the apache build I'm using as the behaviour doesn't seem to be consistant.

Comment: If you do a redirect the request is done. The browser receives the 302. The browser than makes a new request with the new url. So as apache sees it, they are both different requests. Glad you got it working. Sorry about my remark.